# Get a variable from a CMD popup

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I currently am trying to create a batch file in which one of the purposes rely on getting a 6 digit value from the user. It's needed for aesthetics sake that the batch file show a popup message that will have a message requesting the info, and a space for the user to type said info, and obviously a button to confirm.
The issue being that I can't for the life of me figure this out, it's the first time that I am doing some batch scripting, most of my doubts were simple and I was able to advance pretty far on intuition and google alone. I've found a couple methods to generate a message box like

```
mshta "javascript:var sh=new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.Shell' ); sh.Popup( 'Message!', 10, 'Title!', 64 );close()"
```

and

```
@powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('We are proceeding with next step.')"
```

which both work to show a message box, but I can't figure out how to get input from either of those. 
The cmd will be hidden from the user so the only part of it they should see is the message box that will show up. I want to have the user input a value, and the I want to set a variable to that value.
So far what I've been developing is the following code, with changed variables. The important part is the last line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=password
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGPORT=5432
set Arch=x64
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" ( 
    if not defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 set Arch=x86
)
wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" call uninstall
start /D "C:\path\instaladores" /WAIT regedit -v -s path.reg
if %Arch% EQU x64 goto :okpg
if %Arch% NEQ x64 goto :failpg
:failpg
start /D "C:\path\instaladores" /WAIT pg32.exe --mode unattended --superpassword password --servicepassword root --serverport 5432
start /D "C:\path\instaladores" /WAIT Java32.exe INSTALL_SILENT=Enable STATIC=Enable REBOOT=Disable REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=0
goto :continue

:okpg
start /D "C:\path\instaladores" /WAIT pg64.exe --mode unattended --superpassword password --servicepassword root --serverport 5432
start /D "C:\path\instaladores" /WAIT Java64.exe INSTALL_SILENT=Enable STATIC=Enable REBOOT=Disable REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=0
:continue
cd/
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"
psql -d sped -c "select 'ok';"
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 goto :ok
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto :fail
:fail
cd/
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin"
createdb -E WIN1252 -T template0 sped
psql -U postgres -d sped  -c "CREATE ROLE ""user"" LOGIN PASSWORD 'password' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';"
pg_restore.exe --dbname "sped" "C:\SAAM-SPED\instaladores\banco.backup"
psql -U user -d sped  -c "update reg_1102 a set num_reg = '%variableIWant%";
```

which works fine, the issue being how to get the variable I Want in the last line which i can't quite figure out. @Apolymoxic  [sen't me a very helpfull link](https://itfordummies.net/2016/05/09/create-input-box-powershell/)

in which I came up with something like

```
set variableIWant="@powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null; $User = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a user name', 'User', "$env:UserName")""
```

Which I tried for testing, and didn't work, giving an error, I then after some more reading decided to try to make the powershell part set an enviroment variable which looked kinda like this

```
@powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null;$Env:variableIWant = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a Id', 'Id', "$env:variableIWant")"
```

That one didn't return any errors but when I tried to echo the variable on CMD, it doesn't work. That's as far as I was able to get so far. It Seems to me that the command I am using to set the variable on powershell doesn't actually set it on the computer, so when the CMD exits the powershell script the variable ceases to exist, I'm currently trying to figure out how to do it properly but to no avail so far

Comment: Please post your batch file code, we cannot help you with it if we cannot see it? _Please note that Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service; here you are expected to write and test your own code, asking here for help should your code fail to meet it's expacted goals._

Comment: Agree with @Compo
What you might need is a simple Winforms input box where you can get the value of the .Text property, check this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx

Comment: @Compo the reason i din't post my code was that for the question asked, i don't think what i've done so far would matter, but if you this otherwise i can edit the questin and put that in.

Comment: You might check out https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx or https://itfordummies.net/2016/05/09/create-input-box-powershell/. Specifically, I think you need to assign the input box to a variable like $text = [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox], which will assign the input to $text, and then you can use that.

Comment: @MatheusD.Lima, you're looking for an input box which can set a variable from a batch file. You've provided no batch file and some non batch file code to generate message boxes. Taking that into account, your question is asking for something for which you've shown no attempt at trying to produce yourself and as such your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Compo Sorry for that, i didn't see it that way, i will proceed to edit the question and add the needed code

Comment: @Apolymoxic your second link actually gave me some ideas, thanks for that, i might even be able to figure it out my self with that

Comment: @Compo Edited the question with the info you wanted. I think that should be complete now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to do it last night, sorry it took me so long to post it

```
@powershell.exe [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null;$userId = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a Id', 'Id', "$userId"); [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("idUsuario",$userId, "Machine")
exit
```

it's not finished yet, i'll finish the batch file soon, but that is the basic idea that i've come up with, so far it serves the purpose that i want. Thanks everyone for your help

edit: So that didn't work at all and i couldn't figure out why, so what i did is i put the

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null;$userId = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter a Id', 'Id', "$userId"); [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("idUsuario",$userId, "Machine")
```

part in a powershell file, and started it in the cmd script using

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\path\path\ID.ps1
```

which then worked like I needed it to. Just to make it clear, what I does is the powershell bit creates the input box, and sets the value into a regular variable, then I set a machine variable equal to the one from the input, then I can use it on the batch file without any issue.

Sorry for any grammatical errors, i've just woken up and english isn't my first language

Comment: If this is your answer, you should mark it as such, though, it hard to understand how launching powershell to run a vb script is optimal, given that powershell can do pop-ups directly.

Comment: It's also hard to know how setting a variable for future command prompts help with the current program.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic input box example built directly within a batch file:

**InputBox.cmd**

```bat
<!-- :
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') Do Set "_input=%%A"
Echo [%%_input%% = %_input%]
Pause
Exit /B
-->
<HTML><Head><Title>Input number</Title>
        <Script Language="JavaScript">
            window.resizeTo(240,140);
            function CloseHTA(SendOutput){
                if (SendOutput){
                    (new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'))
                        .GetStandardStream(1)
                        .WriteLine(
                            document.getElementById('Number').value);};
                window.close();}
        </Script></Head>
    <Body>
        <Label For="Number">Number:</Label>
        <Input Type="Text" ID="Number">
        <Br>
        <Button OnClick="CloseHTA(true);">OK</Button>
        <Button OnClick="CloseHTA();">Cancel</Button>
    </Body></HTML>
```

Just double click it to test.
*I will leave it to you to adapt it or add any necessary input verification etc.*

Comment: Nice, it would help if it included an explanation of how the value is actually passed from the browser invocation back to the script.  Took me a moment to connect the `WriteLine()` back to the `for /f`.

Answer (score 0):

I would compile a program to do that. Place these three files on your desktop.

**RunAsAdminConsoleInput.vb**

```
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Imports System.IO

Public Module MyApplication  

    Public Sub Main ()
        Dim A as String
        A = InputBox("Enter Something", "My Title", "My default value")
        Console.WriteLine(A)
    End Sub 

End Module
```

**RunAsAdmin.manifest**

Options are `asInvoker`, `highestAvailable`, and `requireAdministrator`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    name="Color Management"
    type="win32"
/>
<description>Serenity's Editor</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"> 
<security> 
    <requestedPrivileges> 
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/> 
    </requestedPrivileges> 
</security> 
</trustInfo> 

</assembly>
```

**RunAsAdminConsoleInput.bat**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdminconsoleInput.vb" /win32manifest:"%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdmin.manifest" /out:"%userprofile%\Desktop\RunAsAdminConsoleInput.exe" /target:exe
```

Double click the batch file to compile.

To use output from a program you use a for loop.

```
for /f "Delims=" %A in ('"%userprofile%\desktop\RunAsAdminConsoleInput"') do Echo %A
```

- Use `%%A` in batch and `%A` when typing interactively.

**NOTE**

Setting a variable in a program does not affect the program that started the program.

Comment: So how exactly does this proposal connect the user input with the batch file?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the Console.WriteLine().